# How do I initialize a multidimensional object array using size() in MATLAB correctly?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am trying to initialize an object array.

From the [MATLAB documentation 1](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html) and [2](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html), I know that you assign the last array element to an object of the and the rest of the array should be filled with default constructed objects. e.g.

```
object_array(2,2) = object; % create 2 x 2 of class 'object'
```

I have done this in several places in my code and it has worked fine.

But I've found that for one of my classes it doesn't work.

I have an object array of objA of size 1x2x2, and I want to create an object array of objB of that size. Now objB has a constructor, and so I've made sure the constructor handles the case that the constructor has no arguments, so that the object array of objB can be default filled. e.g.

```
function objb = objB(parameter)
if (nargin > 0)
% do stuff with parameter
end
end
```

Now here's the funny part:
I try to construct the objB object array using the size of objA array.

```
# breakpoint 1
objBArray(size(objAArray)) = objB;
# breakpoint 2
```

When I reach **breakpoint 1**,

```
size(objAArray) = 1, 2, 2
```

But when I reach **breakpoint 2**,

```
size(objAArray) = 1, 2, 2
```

and

```
size(objBArray) = 1, 2
```

**How come objBArray isn't the same size as objAArray?**

**Is the problem having a constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size(objAArray)` is a vector which MATLAB will treat as indices for assignment. Since `size(objAArray)` is `[1 2 2]`, `objBArray(size(objArray)) = objB` will simply place a reference to `objB` in elements 1, 2, and 2 of the existing `objBArray` array. Since `objBArray` does not exist yet, MATLAB will yield a 1 x 2 array of objects just as it would for normal numbers

```
a([1 2 2]) = 3;
%   3   3

size(a)
%   1   2
```

What you *actually* want instead is

```
a(1,2,2) = 3;   % Instead of a([1 2 2]) = 3
```

To accomplish this, you need to convert `size(objAArray)` to a cell array using `num2cell` and use `{:}` indexing to yield a comma separated list to use as the subscripts since you want *each entry of the vector as a separate subscript for assignment*

```
inds = num2cell(size(objAArray));
objBArray(inds{:}) = objB;
```

Alternately, you could use `repmat` to initialize `objBArray` with the objects obtained using the default constructor.

```
objBArray = repmat(objB(), size(objAArray));
```

Comment: If I was to use the repmat using a handle class objB, would every object in the array point to the same data or would they be independent objects?

Comment: @SamJones They would all be the same default object, unfortunately.

Comment: And as I understand it using the _inds_ subscript method would refer to different data objects as I understand from this [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initializing-arrays-of-handle-objects.html).